# Flutter web app throws error "Uncaught ReferenceError: _flutter is not defined" but it works on some browsers/profiles

Tags: flutter, docker, nginx, dockerfile

Similar to some other errors I've seen floating around... I'm experiencing this console error on the browser while loading my flutter (release) web app on the browser on my domain

`Uncaught ReferenceError: _flutter is not defined`

The strange thing is that this error does NOT show up on only one of my Chrome browser profile and on Firefox (non-private-window).

On every other browser, I get a white screen upon loading my web app.

Additionally, on the browser that the app loads on, the Sources for the page clearly include a `flutter.js` file
[image]

But on the other window where it doesn't load, this is the sources tab
[image]

Im hosting my flutter web app via an nginx server on kubernetes, here is my Dockerfile

```
#Stage 1 - Install dependencies and build the app in a build environment
FROM debian:latest AS build-env

# Install flutter dependencies
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y curl git wget unzip libgconf-2-4 gdb libstdc++6 libglu1-mesa fonts-droid-fallback lib32stdc++6 python3 sed
RUN apt-get clean

# Clone the flutter repo
RUN git clone https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git /usr/local/flutter

# Set flutter path
ENV PATH="${PATH}:/usr/local/flutter/bin:/usr/local/flutter/bin/cache/dart-sdk/bin"

# Run flutter doctor and enable web
RUN flutter doctor
RUN flutter channel stable
RUN flutter upgrade
RUN flutter config --enable-web

# Copy files to container and build
RUN mkdir /app/
COPY . /app/
WORKDIR /app/

RUN flutter clean && flutter pub get && flutter build web

# Stage 2 - Create the run-time image
FROM nginx:1.21.1-alpine
COPY --from=build-env /app/build/web /usr/share/nginx/html
```

When I exec into my flutter-web-app pod and navigate to `/usr/share/nginx/html` folder, I actually DO see the contents I expect to see!

[image]

Wondering where I am going wrong over here! Been dealing with this issue for a couple days now and seemingly nothing I've tried seems to fix it! Open to any ideas!

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

I found the errors of my ways... leaving this post up in case someone else were to experience the same.

So the issue was twofold. It was working on one browser profile as the data was already cached. However, it wasn't on any other browser so the blank screen was indeed the expected behaviour.

The main problem was due to a bad `Ingress` config, which was matching only on `Exact` paths at `/`

When flutter tried to fetch the static file `flutter.js` at `my.domain.name/flutter.js` - it was met with a 404 which was brought about by my ingress default backend.

The solution was to change my `Ingress` rule `spec` to instead do a prefix match on `/app` so that the resource is now requested via the route `my.domain.com/app/flutter.js` - which is not longer met with a 404 - which solves the initial problem I was facing.

TLDR - ensure your ingress rule spec is not too strict!